# MySQL query result doesn't show using AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a database called opera_house with a table called room that has a field room_name and a field capacity. I want to show the room_name 's that have a capacity larger than the one entered by the user.

The Available Room text disappears, but my code only shows the MySQL query if I echo it, but I'm not sure if it is reaching to search the database.

This is my script code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showRoom(str) {
        if (str === "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_events.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

This is my html:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="room" onkeyup="showRoom(this.value)">
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Available Room...</b></div>
</body>
```

This is my php:

```
<?php
    include('dbconnect.php');
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    mysqli_select_db($connection,"opera_house");
    $sql="SELECT room_name FROM room WHERE capacity >= '".$q."'";
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['room_name'] . "</td>";
    }
?>
```

My php file is called ajax_events.php

And my dbconnect.php is one that I constantly use to connect to this database.

Would really appreciate some help!!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Try running the php file from your browser to see what is being returned by the code.

Comment: You've already embedded jQuery, and still you go through all the trouble working with the native XMLHttpRequest implementations poses? You gotta be kidding. This way please, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ...

Answer (score 0):

I propose an answer using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You've embedded it in your question but you're not using it ...

Explanations : You call the following url `ajax_events.php` with the parameter `"q"` only if `str` is defined, otherwise it fills the selector `txtHint` with nothing.

**AJAX**

```
if (str != "") {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax_events.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data : {
      q: str
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
    $('#txtHint').text = data;
  }).fail(function() {
    alert('Fatal error');
  })
} else {
  $('#txtHint').text = '';
}
```

With this configuration, it is important to return result with `echo json_encode` in your server side code.

**PHP**

```
<?php
  include('dbconnect.php');
  $q = intval($_GET['q']);

  mysqli_select_db($connection, "opera_house");
  $sql = 'SELECT room_name FROM room WHERE capacity >= '.$q; // Some corrections
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

  $return = '';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $return .= '<td>' . $row["room_name"] . '</td>';
  }
  echo json_encode($return); // Return Json to ajax
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While thinking of JS it's fine. I think the problems are in the php code. Try this one.

```
 <?php
    include('dbconnect.php');
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    mysqli_select_db($connection,"opera_house");
    $sql="SELECT room_name FROM room WHERE capacity >= " . $q;

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo mysqli_error(); 
        exit();
    } // this is to do debugging. remove when you get it fixed

    $ret = ""; //variable to hold return string
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $ret .= "<td>" . $row['room_name'] . "</td>";
    }

 echo $ret;
```